# How to refer Appendix in a paper?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I put `\label{}` after each section and use `\nameref` with that label name for referring section names in the document. 
But that doesn't work with `\appendix`. What is the correct way to refer a section in a paper?

```
\label{appendix}

\section{Background}
\label{sec:background}
```

How do I refer to background section?

Comment: What exactly do you want `\nameref` to produce when cross-referencing a section contained in the document's appendix, i.e., located after the `\appendix` command?

Comment: The command `\appendix` only reset the counter and change the numbering format to `Alpha`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `nameref` works in the appendix also (as shown in MWE of this answer). Hence without a complete MWE, we won't be able to help.

However, a better idea will be to use the package `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{One}\label{sec:one}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\label{appendix}

\section{Background}
\label{sec:background}
\lipsum[2]

From sections~\nameref{sec:one} and~\nameref{sec:background}, we get the idea of using \verb|nameref| from \verb|hyperref|!

From sections~\ref{sec:one} and~\ref{sec:background}, do we get the idea?

From \cref{sec:one} and~\cref{sec:background}, do we get the idea of using the package \verb|cleveref|?


\end{document}
```

[image]

For details, refer to the package documentation (`texdoc cleveref` from command prompt)

Comment: cleveref is not working with class svjour3

Comment: Hi this is working except since I have changed my appendix name to "Supplementary Material" it should be showing up instead of "appendix" I think. Any way to correct that?