# Cross reference to Appendix doesn't work (showing Section)

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I followed [How to refer Appendix in a paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76518/how-to-refer-appendix-in-a-paper) and tried to refer to an appendix in the main body of the text, but it shows `Section 1` instead of `Appendix A`. Here is the source code.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Refer to \cref{appendix} for more information.

\section{Conclusion}
Draw conclusions here.

\appendix
\section*{Appendix A} \label{appendix}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

How do I display the reference text as `Appendix A`?

Comment: Remove `*`, maybe.

Comment: `\section*` does **not** produce  a number -- to what do you want to refer too? You're grabbing the `\@currentlabel` generated by the last `\refstepcounter`, which was done in the previous `\section`

Comment: @Sigur, it works, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to refer to starred sections (for the appendix, however!)

Redefine `\section` to step a counter for the starred version as well -- this can be fed to `cleveref` with appropiate `cref`-names.

Alternatively, the command `\nameref` from `hyperref` package is clever enough itself to provide the correct name even for starred sections.

Best, don't use starred sections here, this will remove the necessity of numbering them by hand.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{starredsection}%

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \refstepcounter{starredsection}%
      \latex@@section*{#3}%
    }{%
      \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        \latex@@section[#2]{#3}%
      }{%
        \latex@@section{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\crefname{starredsection}{appendix}{appendices}
\Crefname{starredsection}{Appendix}{Appendices}


\begin{document}

Refer to \cref*{appendix} or \nameref*{appendixother} for more information.

\section{Conclusion}
Draw conclusions here.

\appendix
\section*{Appendix A} \label{appendix}

\section*{Appendix B} \label{appendixother}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]